# Discrepancies in retrieving data (dates) from sqlite in ios and android projects

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, datetime, xamarin

I've been using xamarin to create ios and android app to count 'dates'. In the app initialization a series of DateTime data would be injected from text file to sqlite (local database), and in normal process, the app would retrieve these dates from sqlite and execute the code. There are 913 items (of dates) in the local database, and it works fine in ios project but in android project it only retries 712 items from the database. No errors was declared. I've tried to verify the items number (after app initialization) with "var rows = await [name].Table<[model name]>().CountAsync();" and it revealed different results in both ios (913 items) and android projects (712 items). Is there anything I'm missing in project setup?

Comment: The most obvious thing to check would be the code that injects the data into SQLite from a text file.  You could also extract the SQLite file to the desktop and verify it with an SQLite mgmt tool.  But otherwise there isn't enough information in your question to provide any concrete answers.

Comment: The problem is resolved, and it was due to unfinished data injection task method while already executing the remaining codes. Thanks for the orientation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.